# I have an opportunity to do internship at the cost of a gap in my academic year. Should I accept it?

Tags: masters, physics, internship

I have just completed my B.Sc in Physics and I have a unique opportunity to do internship in my field of interest for more than 6 months. If I choose it, I may not be ble to start with my Masters' courses this year and this academic gap will be reflected on my CV. 
I would like to know how will it affect me and my career. My aim is to become a good researcher.

Comment: It isn't a gap if you do something productive with the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to weigh the pros/cons for yourself. There is no right answer to this and will vary for everyone.

Potential benefits:

- More time to build your CV to apply to better universities
- Real-world experience
- Far higher income than graduate assistantships (at least in STEM in the US)
- May provide you insights into your future research directions
- Possibility of publications and patents if the organization does research
- Networking that you may not normally be able to do (and letters of rec)

Potential downsides:

- Delays grad school which probably delays graduation and getting a full-time position
- If you have already been accepted to grad programs, they may not let you postpone them
- Could potentially be a distraction from your long-term goals

Note, I did **5** internships *during* grad school so I obviously value internships. I do suggest to be strategical about internships to see if they are taking you closer to your goals. If so, go for it!

Comment: +1 and I'll add that if the internship deals with research, you'll probably strengthen your CV and graduate application. If it doesn't deal with research, then there's a good chance you'll change your mind about research as a career.